# How to upload Customer Match file to GoogleAds via Python?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm using Python to upload Customer Match file(.csv) to GoogleAds.

Here's my intro code

```
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient

client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_dict(credentials)
```

Then I surf the internet but can't find the function to call

I'm expecting an example code to upload an .csv using object `client`